gdown command not working in jupyter notebook in anaconda.cloud
I am using Jupyter notebook on anaconda.cloud with kernel
anaconda-2024.02-py310.
When I execute the following in a cell:
!pip install gdown
!gdown 1on54WRa6RCAQwrlpE2mABChNs4mNO2fd

It throws the following error:
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in links: /usr/share/pip-wheels
Requirement already satisfied: gdown in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (5.2.0)
...
/bin/bash: gdown: command not found

How come the command not found error is being thrown? Wasn't it just installed and the log also confirms that?
Could someone help me here? I restarted the kernel from the Kernel menu, however it doesn't show any confirmation sort of thing.
I did install gdown on my Mac and this command works on my local host:
gdown 1on54WRa6RCAQwrlpE2mABChNs4mNO2fd
(Of course, I have modified the id a bit here on SO).

Aside: In modern Jupyter everywhere these days you should be using the magic %pip install for a better experience when installing from within a cell. Just mentioning it because propagating outdated information doesn't help anyone. The magic version of the command was added in 2019 to ensure the installation occurs in the environment where the kernel backing the active notebook is running. The exclamation point in conjunction with an install command doesn't do that and so it can lead to issues. There's a related magic %conda install, too.

As to your issue: I suspect you left off some details that spelled out the issue in the part you represented with ...? I just started Anaconda Cloud and ran that pip install gdown in a terminal.  I see the part you pasted in your code block above .... But I also see farther down   WARNING: The script gdown is installed in '/home/fXXXXXXX88-5XX0-4ZZ0-XXX7-4XXXXXXX1/.local/bin' which is not on PATH. Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location. You need to add the program to the path to be able to just call it ...

 on the command line with the name of the program. (Note if you read a lot of posts on here it will say to include the entire error text.) If you don't want to do that you can point at it directly to run it. In my case, /home/fXXXXXXX88-5XX0-4ZZ0-XXX7-4XXXXXXX1/.local/bin/gdown works. BUT YOU ARE USING ANACONDA/CONDA, AND SO YOU SHOULD BE STICKING WITH THAT AS MUCH AS POSSIBLE. With Anaconda/conda, only ever use pip for things without a conda recipe for optimal experience. You would still activate an environment and install there and not in base. I put an answer with that way.

It's a problem with gdown script's path. Install gdwon on a cell with no other instruction
!pip install gdown

There will be a warning about the gdwon script not present in your environment PATH
Installing collected packages: gdown
  WARNING: The script gdown is installed in '/home/<user_id>/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed gdown-5.2.0

In another cell add gdown scritp's path to PATH
import os

# Specify the directory you want to add to PATH
new_directory = '/home/<user_id>/.local/bin'

# Get the current PATH
current_path = os.environ['PATH']

# Add the new directory to the PATH
os.environ['PATH'] = current_path + ':' + new_directory

# Verify the change
print(os.environ['PATH'])

And then run
!gdown <google_file_id>

and it will download wihtout a problem
Downloading...
From: https://drive.google.com/uc?id=<google_file_id>
To: /home/<user_id>/<some_file>
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████| 426k/426k [00:00<00:00, 539MB/s]


Please don't suggest outdated practices. In modern Jupyter, it should be %pip install gdown. The magic command was added in 2019 to insure the install occurs in the environment where the kernel is running that backs the active notebook.  The exclamation point doesn't do that and can lead to issues. See more about the modern %pip install command here. ...

 The second paragraph here goes into more details about why the exclamation point may lead to issues.

I put in my comments that you left out the information that was presented to you at the time you ran the pip install command that it wasn't on the path. If you use Anaconda/conda properly, it will install to the path on its own. (Anacodna/conda has more abilities than pip alone in general, too, and so it is generally more able.) In this case, the Anaconda Cloud is set up to optimally be used with approaches to managing conda environments.  Here's how you'd do that in the Anaconda Cloud session you have:
Start Anaconda Cloud.
Use the Jupyter Launcher to make a terminal inside your Anaconda Cloud session. And run the following to get ready to use conda to create a new environment that you'll use to install gdown in:
conda init
conda create --name gdown_install_test -y 

Now activate your environment. In the terminal type:
conda activate gdown_install_test

Now install gdown using conda in that environment.
In the terminal type:
conda install conda-forge::gdown -y

(That command comes from here. I found that page by searching anaconda gdown in my search engine.)
Now we have a conda environment with gdown installed. We are currently in it and so typing gdown in the terminal right now will show the usage information for gdown, verifying it is installed in that environment.
Next we need to install ipykernel in that environment and we'll set the channel to conda-forge as that includes up to date things. So run in the terminal with that environment we created above still active:
conda install -c conda-forge ipykernel -y
python -m ipykernel install --user --name gdown_install_test

Now open a new notebook form the launched. When I just tried, it defaulted to the new gdown_install_test environment. (Maybe because it was the active environment in the terminal or because I just created it?) You may need to choose it from the launcher or opt in to that kernel by clicking in the upper right side and choose it from the kernel offerings dropdown.
That should open a new active Jupyter notebook.
Now running !gdown in a cell in that active notebook will print the usage becaue it is properly installed in environment that has a kernel you can use in Jupyter.

As written those commands worked for me as I just stepped through it on my Anaconda Cloud session. Obviously, you can name things what you prefer.
Note that if you needed to install via pip because there is no conda-recipe for a dependency, you can now run %pip install <package_name_goes_here> in the the running notebook, replacing <package_name_goes_here> appropriately. Or do that same command in the terminal without the magic symbol at the start, after activating the proper environment, if it isn't already. It is though in your best interest for robust and portable environments to stick with Anaconda/conda as your package manager because you have chosen it as your primary package manager, and not pip, by using Anaconda Cloud. Or if you install an Anconda/conda product on your machine.

Thanks for this detailed answer. I like both the answers. The 'older' version of solution is needed for a constrained work env but I'd use this solution for my independent work.
